# how can i query and view records from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code where i query from three tables, it do query and output the records but my problem example if i have 2 records it will appear many times

codes:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product, product_category, product_subcategory ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $id = $row["product_id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $product_category = $row["product_category"];
    $unit_price = $row["unit_price"];
    $quantity = $row["quantity"];
    $product_subcategory = $row["product_subcategory"];
    $size = $row["size"];
    $color = $row["color"];
    $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));

    $inventory_list .= "Product ID: $id
       -- product_name: $product_name
       -- product category: $product_category
       -- product subcategory: $product_subcategory
       -- size: $size
       -- color: $color 
       -- unit price: $unit_price 
       -- quantity: $quantity 
       -- <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a>
       -- <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
```

after i echo it,
output: (this out should have 2 lines only)

```
Product ID: 9 -- product_name: black shoes -- product category: asd -- product subcategory: formal shoe -- size: 5 -- color: red -- unit price: 12.00 -- quantity: 32 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 9 -- product_name: black shoes -- product category: asd -- product subcategory: asd2 -- size: 12332 -- color: asdas -- unit price: 12.00 -- quantity: 32 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 10 -- product_name: red shoe -- product category: asd -- product subcategory: formal shoe -- size: 5 -- color: red -- unit price: 343.00 -- quantity: 5345 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 10 -- product_name: red shoe -- product category: asd -- product subcategory: asd2 -- size: 12332 -- color: asdas -- unit price: 343.00 -- quantity: 5345 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 9 -- product_name: black shoes -- product category: men shoe -- product subcategory: formal shoe -- size: 5 -- color: red -- unit price: 12.00 -- quantity: 32 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 9 -- product_name: black shoes -- product category: men shoe -- product subcategory: asd2 -- size: 12332 -- color: asdas -- unit price: 12.00 -- quantity: 32 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 10 -- product_name: red shoe -- product category: men shoe -- product subcategory: formal shoe -- size: 5 -- color: red -- unit price: 343.00 -- quantity: 5345 -- edit -- delete
Product ID: 10 -- product_name: red shoe -- product category: men shoe -- product subcategory: asd2 -- size: 12332 -- color: asdas -- unit price: 343.00 -- quantity: 5345 -- edit -- delete
```

Comment: You're using a cross join on the tables, you should use an inner join instead.

Comment: Could you add the schema for tbl_product, product_category and product_subcategory? With that information, some advice about a suitable query can be given. Right now, your problem is the cross join query. This will give a Cartesian product with repeated results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of your column names, but you'll want your query to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product
JOIN product_category ON tbl_product.category_id = product_category.id
JOIN product_subcategory ON tbl_product.subcategory_id = product_subtegory.id
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

That's the explicit way to write it. The implicit way is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product, product_category, product_subcategory
WHERE tbl_product.category_id = product_category.id AND tbl_product.subcategory_id = product_subtegory.id
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Your version produces every possible combination. You have to use ON or WHERE clauses to exclude combinations you don't want. Or in other words, tell it how to join the rows together.